# How to change text padding in android bottom navigation view

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I am using the bottom navigation view for an android app. I have increased the size of my icon, but now the icon runs over the text. Here is what I see:

[image]

Here is a diagram of the bottom navigation view according to google design docs:

[image]

The number 10, I want to change that padding, but when I look in the properties for the navigation bar, I don't see where I can do it. How can I change it to a smaller number? In my bottom_layout.xml I am setting my items up like so:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_notifications"
    android:title="Professionals"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_name"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    />
```

How can I change the bottom text padding?

thanks

Comment: You can tweak the navigation view appearance using styles. [Check this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15679629/7743702)

Answer (score 25):

You change the height of `BottomNavigationView` by overriding the below dimension

```
<dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_height" tools:override="true">52dp</dimen>
```

This will increase the height and bring down the text to avoid overlapping.

Comment: Wow its work like charm. I have face this issue regarding 10" teblet.

Comment: If this isn't working try increasing the height to `>56dp`. Apparently it's 56 by default: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/bottomnavigation/res/values/dimens.xml

Comment: Can you change it just for one bnv in your app? I have more than bnv, and it changes everyone

Answer (score 1):

I was able to change the top and bottom padding of the items using a shape, and setting it in the `app:itemBackground` property of the BottomNavigationView.

Create my_shape.xml, here you can change the top and bottom padding

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="5dp"
        android:top="5dp"
    />
</shape>
```

Then, create my_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:state_checked="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/my_shape" />

</selector>
```

And finally, set the itemBackground of your BottomNavigationView to:

```
app:itemBackground="@drawable/my_selector"
```