# New Bottom Layout from Google

Tags: android, layout, material-design, floating-action-button, material-components-android

First of all, I am sorry to ask a question like this but after I downloaded latest `Google IO` app,

I am just loving the bottom Layout as shown in the following
screenshot

[image]

Being new to android development, I have no clue where to start,  Any idea how to achieve this bottom Layout with circle star in XML? Does anyone know what this design is called?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the new [Material Components for Android](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) and the [**`BottomAppBar`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/BottomAppBar.md) component.

Use something like:

```
 <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
      android:id="@+id/bar"
      android:layout_gravity="bottom"
      app:fabCradleMargin="8dp"
      app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="8dp"
      app:fabCradleVerticalOffset="0dp"
      ... />

  <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
      app:layout_anchor="@id/bar"
      ../>
```

[image]

You have to use these attributes:

- **`fabCradleMargin`** attribute.
  It increases or decreases the distance between the `FloatingActionButton` and the `BottomAppBar`
- **`fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius`** attribute. It specifies the roundness of the corner around the cutout

[image]

**OLD SUPPORT LIBRARY**

With the [Support Library 28.0.0](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#28-0-0), the Design Library contains the `BottomAppBar`.

You can use

```
<android.support.design.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
```

[image]

You can customize the component using these attributes:

- `app:fabAlignmentMode`: Declares the position of the FAB which has been attached to the bottom app bar. This can be either `end` or `center`
- `app:fabCradleVerticalOffset`: Declares the vertical offset to be used for the attached fab. By default this is 0dp.
- `app:backgroundTint`: Used to apply a tint to the background of the view.

Also you you can attach a fab by using `app:layout_anchor` on the FAB component which you wish to attach, using the ID of the bottom app bar.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's the `BottomAppBar`, coming in support library 28.0.0. You can read more here: https://medium.com/@lupajz/the-place-for-bottomappbar-31e0db8f70b1

Comment: Thank you, any idea when will the support library 28 be released ? :)

Comment: You can use the alpha version now, and keep an eye on https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions?authuser=1 for the full release. No idea when that will be though :/

Comment: cheer - I am using xamarin so I don't think xamarin has support for 28 alpha yet

Answer (score 0):

**App bars: bottom**

[Bottom app bars provide access to a bottom navigation drawer and up to four actions, including the floating action button.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HH8Uj.png)

[Bottom app bars can contain actions that apply to the context of the current screen. They include a navigation menu control on the far left and a floating action button (when one is present). If included in a bottom app bar, an overflow menu control is placed at the end of other actions.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHSYO.png)

Informações [enter link description here](https://material.io/design/components/app-bars-bottom.html#anatomy)

```xml
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/FloatingActionButtonAddEmp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_save_black_24px"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/bottom_appbar"/>

<android.support.design.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
    android:id="@+id/bottom_appbar"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:fabAttached="true"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/io15_grey"/>
```