# Bottom Navigation with center button arc or hump

Tags: android, mobile, material-design, bottomnavigationview

Looking to modify the Bottom Navigation Bar with a main center action button which changes the shape of the navigation bar itself either an arc like so
[image]

or a hump in the bottom nav enveloping the center button around it.

I'm fine if I have to extend the `BottomNavigationView` but I don't know where to start.

I found [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50145541/new-bottom-layout-from-google), but it's not the exact problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: Oh poor you! You have iOS designers, designing your Android application :)

Answer (score 3):

Bro, try this

Just place the BottomAppBar and FloatingActionButton into parent CoordinatorLayout and set app:layout_anchor attribute of FloatingActionButton to reference id of BottomAppBar.

> ```
> <android.support.design.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
>     android:id="@+id/bottom_appbar"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_gravity="bottom"
>     app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
>     app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
>     app:fabAttached="true"
>     app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
>     app:fabCradleVerticalOffset="12dp">
>
> </android.support.design.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>
>
> <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
>     android:id="@+id/fab"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
>     android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
>     app:layout_anchor="@+id/bottom_appbar"/>
>
> <FrameLayout
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent">
>
>     <android.support.design.button.MaterialButton
>         android:id="@+id/toggle_alignment"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="48dp"
>         android:layout_gravity="center"
>         android:textColor="#fff"
>         android:text="Toggle FAB alignment"
>         app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"/>
>
> </FrameLayout>
> ```

```
To set menu options you can provide Menu resource to your BottomAppBar in code by calling BottomAppBar.replaceMenu(R.menu.xxx) and to toggle the alignment I created a simple extensions function


import kotlinx...bottom_appbar
import kotlinx...fab
import kotlinx...toggle_alignment
// using kotlin-android-extensions here for findViewById calls
class BottomAppBarActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.actvity_bottom_appbar)

    //setSupportActionBar(bottom_appbar) calling this breaks it!
    // setting the menu
    bottom_appbar.replaceMenu(R.menu.bottom_appbar_menu)
    toggle_alignment.setOnClickListener {
      bottom_appbar.toggleAlignment()
    }
 }
 fun BottomAppBar.toggleAlignment() {
   val current = fabAlignmentMode
   fabAlignmentMode = current.xor(1)
 }
}
```

Comment: This is toolbar, not bottom nav bar as in the question. And the behavior it very different. No ripple effect on buttons

Answer (score 0):

This type of Bottom App Bar comes with Support Library v28. This [article](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/exploring-the-v28-android-design-support-library-2c96c6031ae8) by Joe Birch will be helpful.

Comment: Already went through it but im looking for such behaviour in the `BottomNavigationView`