# Changing bottom navigation bar size

Tags: java, android

I have changed my icon's size but the title isn't fitting within the icon and is looking like 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6y1e.png). The icon size is 40dp.

Here is my code:

```
       <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
          android:id="@+id/navigationBar"
          android:layout_gravity="fill"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="100dp"
          app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_navigation_selection"
          app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_navigation_selection"
          app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation"
          android:background="@color/appBar"/>
```

and here is my dimens.xml:

```
    <dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_icon_size" tools:override="true">50dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_item_max_width" tools:override="true">600dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_active_item_max_width" tools:override="true">600dp</dimen>
```

I hope you guys can help me find a solution. 
Thanks.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43363568/how-to-increase-icon-size-in-android-bottom-navigation-layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following line in your BottomNavigationView:

`app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"`

Example:

```
  <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="@dimen/tv_text_very_small"
        app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@style/BottomNavigationView.Active"
        app:itemTextAppearanceInactive="@style/BottomNavigationView"
        app:itemIconTint="#000000"
        app:itemTextColor="#000000"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_tabs" />
```